# Using a python dictionary of arrays

Tags: python

EDIT: I'm sorry, I realized that I didn't give the full question, this edit should contain the full question. I thougth that my previous question was similar enough to the full question that I could get the answer that way without having to add too many additional details, but I was wrong.

I have a dictionary `params` in python, where each entry is a numpy array of some sort. But the arrays in this dictionary are not all of the same shape. Some are size (n,m), some are size (1,m), some still are totally different sizes. I can call a specific number in this dictionary via:
`params[key][i,j]`

I need to loop over x of the keys in this dictionary, so I have a loop like:

```
for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,(dim of 0th axis of array at key x)):
        for k in range(0,(dim of 1 axis of array at key x)):
            stuff = f(params['W'+str(i)][i,j])
```

I want to create a new dictionary `paramscheck` which will be contain the elements that I'm going to loop over, but the specific numbers in `paramscheck` will be some function of the corresponding numbers in params.

I can't quite figure out the best way to do this.

If I write code like:

```
paramscheck = {}
for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,n):
        for k in range(0,m):
            paramscheck['W'+str(i)][i,j] = f(params['W'+str(i)][i,j])
```

Then I will get that I'm outside the range of the index of paramscheck since that dictionary started out empty.

If I copy `params` to `paramscheck` first and then do the loop with a line like

```
paramscheck = params
```

Then, I won't have issue accessing any entry in paramscheck, but my params dictionary will be modified simultaneously (from what I understand of Python, dictionaries are not actually copied, it just makes an extra label that references to the one underlying dictionary).

I've tried something like `paramscheck = params.copy()` and `paramscheck = dict(params)`, but still the params dictionary is being modified when I go to modify `paramscheck`.

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Is it possible to change `f` so that it can take the array directly? If it involves mathematical operations, like addition, multiplication, thresholding, etc. then it is possible to do so. This would make your life easier.

Comment: I don't believe so...at least I haven't thought of a way in which that could work.

Comment: See Ben Usman's answer for why this is something you should really try to make work. It will be magnitudes faster, depending on the array sizes, and much easier to express.

Comment: "from what I understand of Python, dictionaries are not actually copied, it just makes an extra label that references to the one underlying dictionary" Well, it's not Python dictionaries, it's **all Python objects**, because that is just the semantics of assignment in Python. Assignment **never copies**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your operation is elementwise by nature (e.g. `x + 1`), then you could just use something like

```
def elementwise_f(x):
    return f(x) 

paramscheck = {k: elementwise_f(v) for k, v in array_dict.items()}
```

otherwise something like the following might also work well

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from collections import defaultdict
paramscheck = defaultdict(partial(np.zeros, (10, 20)))  # instead of {}
```

if you want to just initialize new one with old values without changing old values while editing the new one, try `deepcopy` instead of `copy`

```
from copy import deepcopy
paramscheck = deepcopy(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paramscheck = {}
for key in params:
    paramscheck[key] = {} # this line
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,m):
            paramscheck[key][i,j] = f(params[key][i,j])
```

Comment: What if I have to iterate over the keys in params using numbers instead of a key? (Later I will have lines like params['W'+str(i)] to get to the right key, where i is a number I'm running over now)

Comment: he probably meant `paramscheck[key] = np.zeros((n, m))`

Comment: I follow the logic of this answer, but I realized that I didn't give the whole question, so I'm not sure if this answer would still work...I'm going to edit the question. Sorry for the hassle guys, I thought I could write a simplified version of the problem.